# What is the environment for building Ionic1 apps for iOS and Android?

Tags: ionic-framework

Is that even possible in 2019? I tried to build Ionic1 app for iOS and the generated code was no longer supported by XCode. Should that work for Android?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for **Android** is: **yes**.

You may need to start with the blank starter project of **type ionic1** and copy your files over:

```
ionic start blank --type ionic1
```

And you will need the **v1-toolkit**:

```
npm install @ionic/v1-toolkit
```